# How to setup a private network in Docker Swarm?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I am researching how to properly set up a docker swarm infrastructure and there is a problem I still haven't managed to find an answer for.

Let's say, in this basic scenario, I have 2 services:

- API: A Rest API service
- DB: A Database service.

```
     ┌────────┐
     │  WWW   │
     └────────┘
         ▲
         │
 Swarm   │
┌────────┼──────────────────────────┐
│        │                          │
│  ┌─────▼──────┐    ┌───────────┐  │
│  │            │    │           │  │
│  │    API     │◄──►│     DB    │  │
│  │            │    │           │  │
│  └────────────┘    └───────────┘  │
│                                   │
└───────────────────────────────────┘
```

For security purposes, I do not want the DB service to be publicly available. I only want it to be accessibly for services inside the Docker Swarm, ideally I only want it be available for the API service.

I have tried to setup a bridge network (in a docker-compose file), but when using `docker stack deploy` docker complains about it: "*The network ... cannot be used with services. Only networks scoped to the swarm can be used, such as those created with the overlay driver.*".

So, summarizing, my question is:

- How can I setup a network in order to make a service private to the swarm?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a network in this way:

```
docker network create -d overlay my-network
```

and publish only API Service port to make it accessible from outside world